# Reverse the equation to solve for y

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to solve for $Y$ in this equation: 
$\frac {(X-Y)}{Y} = Z.$ 
I tried applying some of the answers from other questions but I'm having special trouble with figuring out how to get the $Y$ out of the parenthesis. Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If $Z\not =-1$, then$$\frac{X-Y}{Y}=Z\Rightarrow X-Y=YZ\Rightarrow X=Y(Z+1)\Rightarrow Y=\frac{X}{Z+1}.$$
Note that $X\not=0$ because $Y\not=0$.

If $Z=-1$, then 
$$\frac{X-Y}{Y}=Z\iff X=Y(Z+1)=0\ \text{and}\ Y\not=0.$$
Hence, $Y$ can be any real number except $0$.

As a result, since $X=0\iff Z=-1$, 
$$Y=\begin{cases}\frac{X}{Z+1}&\text{if $X\not=0\ \text{and}\ Z\not=-1$}\\\text{any real number except $0$}&\text{if $X=0\ \text{and}\ Z=-1$}\end{cases}$$

Comment: If $Z+1 = 0 \Rightarrow X=0$

Answer (score 8):

If a variable is present more than once (the $Y$ in the proposed eq.) then, as a general rule, you should start by removing any fractions and multiplying out any brackets.

Since $Y$ composes the denominator, start by multiplying both sides by $Y$ so that it cancels out on the left:
$$
Y\cdot\frac{(X-Y)}{Y}=Z\cdot Y\;\to\;X-Y=Z\cdot Y
$$
The next step is to put all the terms with $Y$ on the same side of the equation; it can be done by adding $Y$ to both sides:
$$
X-Y+Y=Z\cdot Y+Y\;\to\;X=Z\cdot Y+Y
$$
Now the right hand side can be factorized by the common factor $Y$:
$$  
X=Z\cdot Y+Y=Z\cdot Y+1\cdot Y=Y\cdot(Z+1)  
$$
Then, by dividing both sides by the factor $(Z+1)$ we isolate our variable:
$$  
Y=\frac{X}{Z+1}  
$$
on a last note, think of $(Z+1)$ as one thing by keeping it in the bracket.

*As an advice*, always do one operation as you solve an equation and always do it to both sides, because more complex equations might involve squaring and square-rooting too and other operations. Concentrate on one passage at a time, make a note on what you're doing (adding $Y$, dividing by $(Z+1)$ et similia) and you should get the solution eventually.

Comment: Err...much better obviously...

Comment: Much better answer in my opinion, explains the method's steps in detail, using the equation as an example.